# Write 32 Bit Integer To Buffer In Python

Tags: python, arrays, node.js, python-2.7, buffer

I'm trying to write 32 bit integer to byte array (which is Node.js buffer).

As i know, Node.js Buffer objects `allocUnsafe` function returns array of pseudo-randomly generated numbers encoded in hexadecimal format.

So i interpreted Node.js `Buffer.allocUnsafe(n)` method in Python:

`[c.encode('hex') for c in os.urandom(n)]`

But then, `allocUnsafe` function has its own nested functions `writeInt32BE(value, offset)` and `writeInt32LE(value, offset)`, I have read the official documentation, But i didn't understand what was exactly returned from these functions.

Is there any equivalent method for these Node.js functions in Python? As i know equal action in Python can be done with `struct` module and `from_bytes` method works too, But i'm not sure how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Python provides methods like `int.to_bytes(size,byteorder)` See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)
So in order to convert number to 32 bit we take length in to_bytes method to be 4 i.e `4*8 = 32 bits`.
`int.from_bytes` function converts the bytes to int See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)

```
 >>> n = 512
 >>> n_byte = (n).to_bytes(4,byteorder='big')
 b'\x00\x00\x02\x00'
 >>> int.from_bytes(n_byte,byteorder='big')
 512
```

Default representation in bytes is signed representation of integer.
From docs :

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='big')   16  
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='little')  4096  
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=True)  
-1024  
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=False) 64512  
>>> int.from_bytes([255, 0, 0], byteorder='big')   16711680
```

You can check out the hex representation to converting to integer

```
>>> hex(6)
'0x6'  
>>> int('0xfeedface',16)
4277009102
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. Sorry if i misunderstood, But on Node.js buffer of `28 9f 04 03 01 00 00 00 04 00` returns `6` on `writeUInt32BE` method, But in Python `int.from_bytes(b'(\x9f\x04\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00', "big", signed=False)` returns `191827980698406220727296` Were arguments entered incorrectly? (First argument of the from_bytes function is Node.js's buffer characters decoded in hex).

Comment: @ShellRox Can you drive any logic from the buffer representation for 6 that you presented above.

Comment: Apologies for missing it, I used `Buffer.allocUnsafe(10).writeUInt32BE(2, 2)` to obtain 6.

Comment: By the way, I couldn't understand the similarities, Is there any logic connecting these values?

Comment: @ShellRox If you have read the method in docs correctly. the function writeUInt32BE has arguments integer and offset where offset decide from where to put the representation in buffer. The integer gets converted into hex form and crossponding characters are stored in the buffer. 
`const buff = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);`
`buff.writeUInt32BE(16, 0);` which makes buff `<Buffer 00 00 00 10>` i.e. hex representation stored in Buffer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very sorry for not understanding, I don't know Node.js at higher levels. So for example, Integer `i` which is 4 gets converted in hexadecimal number? `hex(i)` and then how is UInt32BE derived from pseudo-randomly generated buffer? Or is allocUnsafe dependent on something?

Comment: @ShellRox Can you specifically tell what problem you are facing or ask for the community in a fresh question thread. Since your problem has changed much. Do give a shot to reading documentation again hope it helps. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: In short. I'm just trying to create an exact equivalent of `buff.writeUInt32BE(value, offset)` in Python which returns exact value that this method does, As i have noticed, `buff.writeUInt32BE(value, offset)` always returns static value not being dependent on buffer itself. For example, If i wrote `Buffer.allocUnsafe(10).writeUInt32BE(2, 2)` in Node.js, What would be exact equivalent of it in Python? Thank you.

Comment: In docs you can read a line https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_allocunsafe_size Here you will get to know that the integer you want to put inside will be stored in unitialized memory so you will see some random numbers in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I think i have understanding of allocUnsafe, I still don't know how writeUInt32BE works, I guess i will have to read documentation more carefully.

Comment: @ShellRox See here for better understanding https://repl.it/JrwD/4 I can't be more clear than this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That made me understand what offset is instantly and by looking at it more carefully i think it can help me understand more about writeUInt32 method!

Comment: @ShellRox Glad to hear that.